# Header to be separated and convert to a column with seq number and also partial file number in unix

Tags: unix

I have a tab-delimited data file with a header. I want to split off that header and store it in another file, with corresponding sequence and file numbers.

This is the original filename:

```
AllResponses_11003_6_7_20132_17_33AM1.txt
```

This is the information it contains (the first line is the header):

```
"ID"    "NAME"  "LOCAL PLACE"   "CONTACT NUM"
a1      bala    pal             kak
ba1     kri     kap             ute
```

This is the output I would like to obtain, also tab-delimited:

```
seq_num  file_num  header_nm
1        11003     ID
2        11003     NAME
3        11003     LOCAL PLACE
4        11003     CONTACT NUM
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

I tried with following

```
#!/bin/ksh

export INFAHOME=/informat/PowerCenter/9.1.0/server/infa_shared
export SRCDIR=${INFAHOME}/SrcFiles/CSI/INCOMING
export filename=${SRCDIR}/AllResponses_11003_6_7_20132_17_33AM1.txt
export filenum=$(echo $filename | tr -dc 0-9 |cut -c 1-5)
echo seq_num file_num hname
cnt=1
for h in $(head -1 "$filename" )
do
   echo $cnt $filenum $h cnt=$((cnt+1))
done
```

It is giving for word to word not for delimitor to delimitor

This the code i built with your help using awk but not working. Pl help.

```
#!/bin/ksh

export INFAHOME=/informat/PowerCenter/9.1.0/server/infa_shared
export SRCDIR=${INFAHOME}/SrcFiles/CSI/INCOMING
export file=${SRCDIR}/AllResponses_11003_6_7_20132_17_33AM1.txt
export file1=AllResponses_11003_6_7_20132_17_33AM1.txt
export name=$(echo $file1 | cut -d_ -f2) #gets 11003

$ awk -v file=$name -F"\t" 'BEGIN{print "seq_num\tfile_num\theader_nm"} NR==1 {for (i=1`enter code here`;i<=NF;i++) {print i"\t"file,"\t"$i}}' $file
```

getting below error. Pl help

> - file=11003 '-F\t' 'BEGIN{print "seq_num\tfile_num\theader_nm"} NR==1 {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {print i"\t"file,"\t"$i}}'
>     /informat/PowerCenter/9.1.0/server/infa_shared/SrcFiles/CSI/INCOMING/AllResponses_11003_6_7_20132_17_33AM1.txt
>     CSI_SURVEY_FILE_CREA.ksh: line 7: v not found

Hi I need one more favour...
I need to pass file names dynamically and for each file need to create separate output file. Pl help.

Comment: Is there anything you've tried that didn't work?

Comment: yeah..tried with following  #!/bin/ksh
export INFAHOME=/informat/PowerCenter/9.1.0/server/infa_shared
export SRCDIR=${INFAHOME}/SrcFiles/CSI/INCOMING

export filename=${SRCDIR}/AllResponses_11003_6_7_20132_17_33AM1.txt
export filenum=$(echo $filename | tr -dc 0-9 |cut -c 1-5)
echo seq_num file_num hname
cnt=1
for h in $(head -1 "$filename" )
do
    echo $cnt $filenum $h
    cnt=$((cnt+1))
done

Comment: it is giving for word to word not for delimitor to delimitor

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to do it with a mixure of awk and bash:

```
$ file="AllResponses_11003_6_7_20132_17_33AM1.txt"
$ name=$(echo $file | cut -d_ -f2) #gets 11003
$ awk -v file=$name -F"\t" 
      'OFS="\t"; print "seq_num","file_num","header_nm"}
       NR==1 {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {print i,file,$i}}' $file
seq_num file_num        header_nm
1       11003   "ID"
2       11003   "NAME"
3       11003   "LOCAL PLACE"
4       11003   "CONTACT NUM"
```

Given

```
file="AllResponses_11003_6_7_20132_17_33AM1.txt"
```

The line

```
name=$(echo $file | cut -d_ -f2) #gets 11003
```

gets `1111` from the string `XXXX_1111_YYY_ZZZ_...`. Then this value is saved in `$name` so that `awk` can use it.

```
awk -v file=$name -F"\t" 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"; print "seq_num","file_num","header_nm"} NR==1 {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {print i,file,$i}}' $file
```

- `-v file=$name`. Makes `file` a variable to be used by awk with the value of `$name`.
- `-F"\t"`. Sets tab as delimiter.
- `'BEGIN{print "seq_num","file_num","header_nm"}`. Prints the header before processing the file.
- `NR==1`. Just works with first line.
- `{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {print i,file,$i}}' $file`. Prints each field number + $name + value.

Comment: #!/bin/ksh
export INFAHOME=/informat/PowerCenter/9.1.0/server/infa_shared
export SRCDIR=${INFAHOME}/SrcFiles/CSI/INCOMING
export file=${SRCDIR}/AllResponses_11003_6_7_20132_17_33AM1.txt
export name=$(echo $file | cut -d_ -f2) #gets 11003
$ awk -v file=$name -F"\t" 'BEGIN{print "seq_num\tfile_num\theader_nm"} NR==1 {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {print i"\t"file,"\t"$i}}' $file

tried with your code...but not working...pls help

Comment: My code is stand alone, should be enough for your purpose. Anyway, if you want to integrate it to your current code, please update your question with the current code so I can see it better (the format in the comments is very hard to understand code).

Comment: + '$' awk -v file=11003 '-F\t' 'BEGIN{print "seq_num\tfile_num\theader_nm"} NR==1 
{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {print i"\t"file,"\t"$i}}' 
/informat/PowerCenter/9.1.0/server/infa_shared/SrcFiles/CSI/INCOMING/AllResponses_11003_6_7_20132_17_33AM1.txt
CSI_SURVEY_FILE_CREA.ksh: line 7: $: not found  ----this is the error iam getting..pls help

Comment: As I said before, update your question with the code and the errors, do not post them in comments.

Comment: sorry for posting in comments. please see my updated question

Comment: OK now I see. You don't have to put the `$` in the beginning of the line. It is a copy&paste from my prompt. The line must start with just `awk -v file...`.